# Spritekit - UIScrollview prevents touches began etc. from functioning

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

Does anyone know how can I get touches began etc. to function on SKSpritenodes when there is a UIScrollView added?. Currently the UIScrollView is just added itself.

I assume somehow It needs to be a child of the SKScene but all attempts have failed.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
pageScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-700, self.frame.size.height)];
pageScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1530, self.frame.size.height);
pageScroller.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
pageScroller.delegate = self;
[self.scene.view addSubview:pageScroller];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

    sprite.xScale = 0.5;
    sprite.yScale = 0.5;
    sprite.position = location;

    SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];

    [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];

    [self addChild:sprite];
}
}
```

Comment: 1) why is this being done in the scene? this should be done in the view 2) your pageScroller is overlapping your scene,  so do you want to scroll, or do you want to touch

Comment: Want to both scroll and touch. I'm creating a level select screen therefore I want both if its possible. Are you saying I should create a SKView and add the UIScrollview to this?

Comment: You do not want a scroll view for what you are doing,  Treat SpriteKit and UIKit as 2 different things,  they are not compatable.  what you want to be doing is creating a parent node for all of your objects to be placed into, make a touch and drag gesture,  and move the parent node on your scene

Comment: thats a shame, I've made a entire game combining both elements of UIKit and Spritekit. Guess I will instead create UIButtons and use the touch effect this way and thus scrolling will also work.

Comment: what? you are using sprite kit as buttons

Comment: In some instances yes. Hence why I use the touches began method to perform a action depending on the name of the node

Answer (score 0):

Done, the aim of this was to create a level box select screen that has

- Scrollable scene (Boxes 1,2,3,4 which are clickable)
- Navigation boxes 1-4 which tells you which the currently viewed box is (scroll- NO)
- Snapping to specific positions depending on current scroll location.
- Tapping the navigation boxes to go to the specific box

Heres all the code if someone finds this useful and heres a video of it in action.
http://www.performancetrackerltd.com/#!tutorials/syjol

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
pageScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-700, self.frame.size.height)];
pageScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1530, self.frame.size.height);
pageScroller.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
pageScroller.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:pageScroller];

[self addBoxLevels];

navigationBox1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
navigationBox1.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 30.0, 30.0);
navigationBox1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navigationBox1.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-928, self.frame.size.height-300);
[navigationBox1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxFilled"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox1 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox1];
[navigationBox1 addTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBox1Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

navigationBox2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
navigationBox2.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 30.0, 30.0);
navigationBox2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navigationBox2.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-895, self.frame.size.height-300);
[navigationBox2 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox2 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox2];
[navigationBox2 addTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBox2Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

navigationBox3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
navigationBox3.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 30.0, 30.0);
navigationBox3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navigationBox3.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-862, self.frame.size.height-300);
[navigationBox3 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox3 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox3];
[navigationBox3 addTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBox3Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

navigationBox4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
navigationBox4.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 30.0, 30.0);
navigationBox4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navigationBox4.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-829, self.frame.size.height-300);
[navigationBox4 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox4 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox4];
[navigationBox4 addTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBox4Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 }
-(void)navigationBox1Action{
[pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
 }
 -(void)navigationBox2Action{
[pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(300, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
 }
 -(void)navigationBox3Action{
[pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(600, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
 }
  -(void)navigationBox4Action{
[pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(900, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
  }

 -(void)navigationBoxes{
 if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 200) {
UIImage *navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxFilled"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox1 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox1];
UIImage *navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox2 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox2];
UIImage *navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox3 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox3];
UIImage *navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
UIImage *strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[navigationBox4 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBox4];
 } else {
if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 200 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 450) {
    UIImage *navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
    UIImage *strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [navigationBox1 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBox1];
    UIImage *navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxFilled"];
    UIImage *strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [navigationBox2 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBox2];
    UIImage *navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
    UIImage *strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [navigationBox3 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBox3];
    UIImage *navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
    UIImage *strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [navigationBox4 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBox4];
} else {
    if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 451 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 750) {
        UIImage *navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
        UIImage *strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
        [navigationBox1 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:navigationBox1];
        UIImage *navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
        UIImage *strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
        [navigationBox2 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:navigationBox2];
        UIImage *navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxFilled"];
        UIImage *strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
        [navigationBox3 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:navigationBox3];
        UIImage *navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
        UIImage *strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
        [navigationBox4 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:navigationBox4];
    } else {
        if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 750 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 1000) {
            UIImage *navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
            UIImage *strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
            [navigationBox1 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:navigationBox1];
            UIImage *navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
            UIImage *strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
            [navigationBox2 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:navigationBox2];
            UIImage *navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
            UIImage *strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
            [navigationBox3 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:navigationBox3];
            UIImage *navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxFilled"];
            UIImage *strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
            [navigationBox4 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:navigationBox4];
        } else {
            if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 1001 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 1300) {
                UIImage *navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
                UIImage *strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox1BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
                [navigationBox1 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox1BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.view addSubview:navigationBox1];
                UIImage *navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
                UIImage *strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox2BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
                [navigationBox2 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox2BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.view addSubview:navigationBox2];
                UIImage *navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
                UIImage *strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox3BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
                [navigationBox3 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox3BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.view addSubview:navigationBox3];
                UIImage *navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxClear"];
                UIImage *strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal = [navigationBox4BackStateImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
                [navigationBox4 setBackgroundImage:strechablenavigationBox4BackStateImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.view addSubview:navigationBox4];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

 -(void)addBoxLevels{
_season1TotalStars = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"_season1TotalStars"];

season1Box1Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
season1Box1Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
season1Box1Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
season1Box1Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-855, self.frame.size.height-500);
[season1Box1Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *season1Box1ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box1"];
UIImage *strechableSeason1Box1ImageButton = [season1Box1ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[season1Box1Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box1ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pageScroller addSubview:season1Box1Button];
[season1Box1Button addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToSeasons1Box1Levels) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (_season1TotalStars >= 40) {
    season1Box2Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    season1Box2Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
    season1Box2Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //    season1Box2Button.center = CGPointMake(470,250);
    season1Box2Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-555, self.frame.size.height-500);
    [season1Box2Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *season1Box2ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box2"];
    UIImage *strechableSeason1Box2ImageButton = [season1Box2ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [season1Box2Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box2ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageScroller addSubview:season1Box2Button];
    [season1Box2Button addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToSeasons1Box2Levels) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
} else {
    season1Box2Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    season1Box2Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
    season1Box2Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //    season1Box2Button.center = CGPointMake(470,250);
    season1Box2Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-555, self.frame.size.height-500);
    [season1Box2Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *season1Box2ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box2lock"];
    UIImage *strechableSeason1Box2ImageButton = [season1Box2ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [season1Box2Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box2ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageScroller addSubview:season1Box2Button];
    [season1Box2Button addTarget:self action:@selector(IAPunlockSeason1Box2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    levelBox2StarCountToUnlock = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
    levelBox2StarCountToUnlock.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    levelBox2StarCountToUnlock.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
    levelBox2StarCountToUnlock.text = @"40";
    levelBox2StarCountToUnlock.enabled = NO;
    levelBox2StarCountToUnlock.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-495, self.frame.size.height-492);
    [pageScroller addSubview:levelBox2StarCountToUnlock];
}

if (_season1TotalStars >= 90) {
    season1Box3Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    season1Box3Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
    season1Box3Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //    season1Box3Button.center = CGPointMake(770,250);
    season1Box3Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-255, self.frame.size.height-500);
    [season1Box3Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *season1Box3ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box3"];
    UIImage *strechableSeason1Box3ImageButton = [season1Box3ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [season1Box3Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box3ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageScroller addSubview:season1Box3Button];
    [season1Box3Button addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToSeasons1Box3Levels) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
} else {
    season1Box3Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    season1Box3Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
    season1Box3Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //    season1Box3Button.center = CGPointMake(770,250);
    season1Box3Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-255, self.frame.size.height-500);
    [season1Box3Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *season1Box3ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box3lock"];
    UIImage *strechableSeason1Box3ImageButton = [season1Box3ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [season1Box3Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box3ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageScroller addSubview:season1Box3Button];
    [season1Box3Button addTarget:self action:@selector(IAPunlockSeason1Box3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    levelBox3StarCountToUnlock = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
    levelBox3StarCountToUnlock.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    levelBox3StarCountToUnlock.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
    levelBox3StarCountToUnlock.text = @"90";
    levelBox3StarCountToUnlock.enabled = NO;
    levelBox3StarCountToUnlock.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-195, self.frame.size.height-492);
    [pageScroller addSubview:levelBox3StarCountToUnlock];
}

if (_season1TotalStars >=180) {
    season1Box4Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    season1Box4Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
    season1Box4Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //    season1Box4Button.center = CGPointMake(1070,250);
    season1Box4Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+45, self.frame.size.height-500);
    [season1Box4Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *season1Box4ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box4"];
    UIImage *strechableSeason1Box4ImageButton = [season1Box4ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [season1Box4Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box4ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageScroller addSubview:season1Box4Button];
    [season1Box4Button addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToSeasons1Box4Levels) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
} else {
    season1Box4Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    season1Box4Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 250.0, 250.0);
    season1Box4Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //    season1Box4Button.center = CGPointMake(1070,250);
    season1Box4Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+45, self.frame.size.height-500);
    [season1Box4Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *season1Box4ButtonImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box4lock"];
    UIImage *strechableSeason1Box4ImageButton = [season1Box4ButtonImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [season1Box4Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason1Box4ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageScroller addSubview:season1Box4Button];
    [season1Box4Button addTarget:self action:@selector(IAPunlockSeason1Box4) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    levelBox4StarCountToUnlock = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
    levelBox4StarCountToUnlock.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    levelBox4StarCountToUnlock.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:23.0];
    levelBox4StarCountToUnlock.text = @"180";
    levelBox4StarCountToUnlock.enabled = NO;
    levelBox4StarCountToUnlock.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+107, self.frame.size.height-493);
    [pageScroller addSubview:levelBox4StarCountToUnlock];
}
season2Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
season2Button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 200.0, 200.0);
season2Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
season2Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+345, self.frame.size.height-500);
[season2Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *season2ImageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"season3"];
UIImage *strechableSeason2ImageButton = [season2ImageButton stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[season2Button setBackgroundImage:strechableSeason2ImageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pageScroller addSubview:season2Button];
[season2Button addTarget:self action:@selector(movetoSeason2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

season2Label = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
season2Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
season2Label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:23.0];
season2Label.text = @"Season 2";
season2Label.enabled = NO;
season2Label.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+397, self.frame.size.height-618);
[pageScroller addSubview:season2Label];

season2LabelComingSoonLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
season2LabelComingSoonLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
season2LabelComingSoonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:23.0];
season2LabelComingSoonLabel.text = @"Coming soon";
season2LabelComingSoonLabel.enabled = NO;
season2LabelComingSoonLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+375, self.frame.size.height-380);
[pageScroller addSubview:season2LabelComingSoonLabel];
  }


 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)pageScroller
 {
       [self stoppedScrolling];
  }

  - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)pageScroller
              willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
 {
if (!decelerate) {
          [self stoppedScrolling];
}
 }

  - (void)stoppedScrolling
  {
          if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 160) {
        [pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    } else {
        if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 161 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 399) {
            [pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(300, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
        } else {
            if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 400 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 700) {
                [pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(600, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
            } else {
                if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 701 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 1050) {
                    [pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(900, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
                } else {
                    if (pageScroller.contentOffset.x > 1051 & pageScroller.contentOffset.x < 1300) {
                        [pageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1200, pageScroller.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
                    } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }

  -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
[self navigationBoxes];
  }
```

Comment: yikes, this is some scary stuff here,  you should really learn how to maintain your code so that each class has a specific purpose.  This makes your code easier to read and maintain. You should have a custom class for your page scroller, and have all this menu code inside of that, inside of your scene.  The scene should know nothing about views,  its job is to render gfx.  Also, you do not need to branch your `if, else` like that,  `else if` is an acceptable term in swift, so you can do `if, else if, else`

Comment: yep I agree, its very messy. Something I need to learn so I can do it better. At least the functionality is working for now. I imagine, I'm going to hit memory problems at some point also which is going to be a huge problem.